# Missing links when specific baseline is determined

Tags: ibm-doors, baseline, ibm-rational

I wrote a DXL script that I run from a batch file. This script creates text file where all "requirements data" within module are written. There are also all outlinks within each requirement. This works fine.

```
string file_location_latest = "output_latest.txt"
string file_location_all = "output_all.txt"

Stream out_latest = write file_location_latest
Stream out_all = write file_location_all

Object o
Module m
Link outLink

m = read("/PATH/TO/MODULE",true)

for o in entire(m) do {
    out_all << "<<<REQUIREMENT>>><<<ID>>>"identifier(o)"<<<LEVEL>>>"level(o)"<<<HEADING>>>"o."Object Heading""<<<COLUMN>>>"o."802_Comment""\n\n"

    for outLink in o -> "*" do {
            out_all << "\n<OUTLINK_START>"(fullName targetVersion outLink) ":" (targetAbsNo (outLink)) "<OUTLINK_END>\n"         
    }    
    
}
```

But now I need the same procedure but not to a whole module but to specific baseline. I wrote another script. It works also fine BUT there is one problem: All links which point to this (same) module are missing. What am I doing wrong?

```
Module mBaseline_latest = load (m, getMostRecentBaseline(m, false), false)

for o in entire(mBaseline_latest) do {
    out_latest << "<<<REQUIREMENT>>><<<ID>>>"identifier(o)"<<<LEVEL>>>"level(o)"<<<HEADING>>>"o."Object Heading""<<<COLUMN>>>"o."802_Comment""\n\n"

    for outLink in o -> "*" do {
            out_latest << "\n<OUTLINK_START>"(fullName targetVersion outLink) ":" (targetAbsNo (outLink)) "<OUTLINK_END>\n"         
    }    
    
}
```

If I check the links within this Baseline in GUI Doors, the links are there. So the problem is really on my side.

Thank you.

Comment: you say "links TO this module". Do you mean incoming links? Your script reports links going away from objects (outgoing links, red arrows to the right, `o -> "*"`))

Answer (score 0):

depending on your requirements, you might miss links that only go to a baseline, not to a current version. These will be reported using the perm "for outlink in `all` o->". See chapter "Versioned Links" in the DXL manual

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. That was exactly what I needed.